# Sull'ordine delle parole in una frase particolare

Tags: word-order

Nel romanzo *Marco Polo* di Maria Bellonci ho letto questa frase:

> «All'uscita di un passo più degli altri pericoloso vedemmo un altare buddista di pietra informa conica, eretto su un piedistallo quadrato.»

L'ordine delle parole in "*un passo più degli altri pericoloso*" mi è sembrato molto curioso perché là io avrei scritto "un passo più pericoloso degli altri". Sapreste spiegarmi il perché di tale ordine dei vocaboli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come già risposto da Elberich Schneider, è una questione di enfasi.

La figura retorica è quella dell'inversione, spesso abusata dagli scrittori alle prime armi per darsi un tono (classico esempio è l'aggettivo prima del sostantivo).

In questo caso l'inversione funziona perché il tono della voce (anche quella interiore di quando si legge silenziosamente) è costretto a seguire un percorso più tortuoso rispetto a quello normale.

Nella frase

> un passo *più* pericoloso *degli altri*

il tono della voce ha un andamento quasi lineare: si riprende fiato scandendo la frase in "un-passo", "più-pericoloso", "degli-altri".

Invece, in

> un passo *più degli altri* pericoloso

lo spostamento del complemento di specificazione costringe il tono di voce ad innalzarsi per più tempo: "un-passo", "più-degli-altri", "pericoloso". Questo fa cadere l'attenzione su "**p**ericoloso" piuttosto che su "**p**iù".

Answer (score 2):

'All'uscita di *un passo più degli altri pericoloso* vedemmo un altare buddista di pietra in forma conica, eretto su un piedistallo quadrato.'

È una mera questione di enfasi, e funziona.

Quell'ordine di parole significa che già gli altri passi incontrati erano di per loro particolarmente pericolosi — per ragioni peculiari anche se non specificate — e che quello in argomento lo era finanche di più.

Il tuo ordine di parole ('un passo più pericoloso degli altri') lascerebbe invece pensare, per gli altri, ad una pericolosità molto generica come quella tipica di tanti altri passi nel mondo; un po' come quando su una strada trovi il segnale di pericolo generico.